# OpenCV for Android does not draw rectangle around face for face detection on phone screen but does draw rectangle on emulator screen in Android Studio

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection

The OpenCV face detection program does not draw the rectangles around the faces on my phone screen (Nexus 4) but it does draw the rectangles on the emulator in Android Studio. Here is the code:

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat aInputFrame) {
    // Create a grayscale image[enter image description here][1]
    Imgproc.cvtColor(aInputFrame, grayscaleImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

    MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();
    MatOfRect eye = new MatOfRect();

    // Use the classifier to detect faces
    if (faceDetect != null ) {
        faceDetect.detectMultiScale(grayscaleImage, faces, 1.1, 2, 2,
                new Size(absoluteFaceSize, absoluteFaceSize), new Size());

        Log.d(TAG,"Face Detected");

    }

    // If there are any faces found, draw a rectangle around it
    Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();

    for (int i = 0; i <facesArray.length; i++) {
        Rect rG = facesArray[i];
        Imgproc.rectangle(aInputFrame, rG.tl(), rG.br(), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
    }


    if(eyeDetect != null ){
        eyeDetect.detectMultiScale(grayscaleImage, eye, 1.1, 2, 2,
                new Size(absoluteEyeSize, absoluteEyeSize), new Size());

        Log.d(TAG,"Eyes Detected");
    }

    Rect[] eyeArray = eye.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i <eyeArray.length; i++) {
        Rect rR = eyeArray[i];
        Imgproc.rectangle(aInputFrame, rR.tl(), rR.br(), new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3);
    }

    return aInputFrame;
}
```

The green and red rectangles are drawn in emulator, but not in my phone.
Please let me know how to fix this. I am using Android Studio 2.2 and OpenCVLibray310.

Comment: Are you sure it detects some faces in your phone?

Comment: Yes, it does detect. The rectangle doesn't appear even on the face-detection API provided by OpenCV in samples folder.

Comment: How are you sure it detects something in your phone? Do you print some log or something? The obvious supposition is that you didn't load the classifiers correctly, so it doesn't detect anything, and so there are no rectangles to draw...

Comment: Can you please tell me how do I print some log in console for every frame it detects and for every frame it does not? Where do I write my log statement?

Comment: I don't know... I don't work with Android... You can probably print to a file, and check the file after execution

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help.